# DataGrid not updating right away

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, command

In my program I have a `DataGrid` implemented through MVVM. Next to this `DataGrid` is a button that executes a command that I've named, "Fill Down". It takes one of the columns and copies a string to every cell in that column. The problem is that the view doesn't make the change until I change the page and then go back to the page with the `DataGrid`. Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

xaml:

```
<Button Command="{Binding FillDown}" ... />
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataModel.Collection}" ... />
```

ViewModel:

```
private Command _fillDown;

public ViewModel()
{
     _fillDown = new Command(fillDown_Operations);
}

//Command Fill Down
public Command FillDown { get { return _fillDown; } }
private void fillDown_Operations()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DataModel.NumOfCells; i++)
    {
        DataModel.Collection.ElementAt(i).cell = "string";
    }
    //**I figured that Notifying Property Change would solve my problem...
    NotifyPropertyChange(() => DataModel.Collection);
}
```

-Please let me know if there is anymore code you would like to see.

**Yes, sorry my Collection is an `ObservableCollection`**

Comment: Is your collection an ObservableCollection?

Comment: @Doc It doesn't matter. The OP is not adding / removing items from the collection.

Comment: @HighCore Good point -- I guess he'd need to notify property changed on each element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call NotifyPropertyChanged() in the setter of your properties:

```
public class DataItem
{
   private string _cell;
   public string cell //Why is your property named like this, anyway?
   {
       get { return _cell; }
       set
       {
           _cell = value;
           NotifyPropertyChange("cell");

           //OR

           NotifyPropertyChange(() => cell); //if you're using strongly typed NotifyPropertyChanged.
       }
   }
}
```

**Side Comment:**

change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataModel.NumOfCells; i++)
{
    DataModel.Collection.ElementAt(i).cell = "string";
}
```

to this:

```
foreach (var item in DataModel.Collection)
    item.cell = "string";
```

which is much cleaner and readable.

Comment: Thanks. My property is only named "cell" for the example.